# C# Retry two queries with Polly Retry

Tags: c#, .net, polly, retry-logic

So I have 2 queries:

```
var a = await _aQuery.Execute(aId);
var b = await _bQuery.Execute(bId);
```

How can I retry execution of these queries with Polly Retry so that if any of them succeeds to get a non-null value, the code can proceed?

For example: 5 retries every 200ms and if query succeeds on `a` or on `b`, break the retries and proceed.

Comment: There are lots of examples available on the link below.  https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: I looked at it but couldn't find what I wanted.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: *retries every 200ms* << Did you mean 200 milliseconds delay between each retry attempts, right?

Comment: yes thats correct, but the timing isn't a problem, the problem is how to wrap these two queries to be retried instead of retrying them one by one

Answer (score 3):

Let me alter your two operations a bit for the sake of simplicity.

```
static Random rnd = new();
static async Task<int?> OperationA()
{
    await Task.Delay(100); //Simulate I/O call's latency
    var number = rnd.Next();
    return number % 5 == 0 ? number : null;
}

static async Task<int?> OperationB()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);  //Simulate I/O call's latency
    var number = rnd.Next();
    return number % 4 == 0 ? number + 1 : null;
}
```

- We have two operations (`OperationA` and `OperationB`) and they will either return `null` or an `int`
- Their implementation are not important, they just serve demonstration purposes

---

Now If you need to define a retry policy which

- Triggers if both operations failed
- Triggers at most 5 times
- Delays 200 milliseconds between each attempt

then you can do that like this:

```
var retryUntilGetResult = Policy<(int?, int?)>
    .HandleResult(((int? OpA, int? OpB) results) => !results.OpA.HasValue && !results.OpB.HasValue)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 5, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
```

- The `Policy<(int?, int?)>` part says that your return type is a tuple with two nullable integers
- The `HandleResult` part says that if the returned tuple (`results`) does not contain any integer (`!...HasValue`) then the policy should trigger
- The `WaitAndRetryAsync` part says you want to decorate an async method with this policy
- The policy should fire at most 5 times, but wait 200 milliseconds between each attempt

---

The usage of this policy looks like this:

```
var result = await retryUntilGetResult.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
{
    Task<int?> opA = OperationA();
    Task<int?> opB = OperationB();
    await Task.WhenAll(opA, opB);
    return (await opA, await opB);
});
```

- We fire of two Tasks and we are waiting for both to complete
- Then we return a new tuple where we pass the results of the async operations

---

For the sake of completeness here the full source code:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var retryUntilGetResult = Policy<(int?, int?)>
        .HandleResult(((int? OpA, int? OpB) results) => !results.OpA.HasValue && !results.OpB.HasValue)
        .WaitAndRetryAsync(retryCount: 5, _ => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));

    var result = await retryUntilGetResult.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
    {
        Task<int?> opA = OperationA();
        Task<int?> opB = OperationB();
        await Task.WhenAll(opA, opB);
        return (await opA, await opB);
    });
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

static Random rnd = new();
static async Task<int?> OperationA()
{
    await Task.Delay(100); //Simulate I/O call's latency
    var number = rnd.Next();
    return number % 5 == 0 ? number : null;
}

static async Task<int?> OperationB()
{
    await Task.Delay(100);  //Simulate I/O call's latency
    var number = rnd.Next();
    return number % 4 == 0 ? number + 1 : null;
}
```